# Using Flash on Mac

Tags: flash-player

I would like to completely remove the time bomb from Flash Player on MacOS. I tried configuring it using the mms.cfg file, but I use multiple sites with Flash content and i would prefer to remove the time bomb entirely.

Comment: The trouble with closing this as a dupe is that every single answer on the linked page is for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Flash itself was time-bombed to stop working on 21 Jan 2021. Safari 14 will not allow it at all, so I'd guess you're stuck with using an old OS in a VM.

Set the VM's clock back & switch off all updates.
You'll probably have to use High Sierra which can't use Safari 14 & you'd need to find or already have an older version of the Adobe Flash offline installer, as it's not available any more from Adobe. All flash downloads were removed last month.

Note that this was first announced three years ago, so your developer has had plenty of time to remove reliance on this dangerous, old technology.